# Running exe file during uninstallation from a customized folder location

Tags: directory, wix, exe, custom-action, uninstallation

I need to run an executable file (.exe) during the uninstall. The .exe file is located in say APPEXTRACTIONPATH folder (value is provided by the user during installation). Is it doable?

The location info is present in one of the registry key as well. **Is it possible to read the registry during uninstall, pass the location to the "Directory" and run the .exe file from that location.** Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Code snippet:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" >
    <Directory Id="LICENSEFILEPATH" Name="LicenseFileDir">
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="APPEXTRACTIONPATH" Name="AppExtractDir">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>


<CustomAction Id  ="ExecuteSomeExe"
          Directory   ="APPEXTRACTIONPATH"
          ExeCommand  ="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start SomeExe.exe &amp; exit"
          Execute     ="deferred"
          Impersonate ="no"
          Return      ="asyncNoWait"
                  />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
... ... ...
<Custom Action="ExecuteSomeExe" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I also tried to use vbscript in the CustomAction to run the .exe file after reading the location from the registry key. The location is read perfectly, but execution isn't happening.

```
<CustomAction Id="ExecuteSomeExe"
              Execute="deferred"
              Script="vbscript"
              >
  <![CDATA[
  On error resume next

  Dim WshShell1
  Dim WshShell2
  Dim appExtractPath
  Dim fullExecPath




  Set WshShell1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  appExtractPath = WshShell1.RegRead ("HKCU\Software\MyCompany\MyApp\AppExtractionPath")
  msgbox "App Extraction Path = "&appExtractPath

  Set WshShell2 = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
  fullExecPath = appExtractPath &"SomeExe.exe"
  msgbox "Before running exe from " &fullExecPath
  'Running .exe file
  WshShell2.Run(fullExecPath)
  msgbox "After running exe from " &fullExecPath
  'Trying to run in another way
  WshShell2.Run "cmd /K CD "&appExtractPath&" & SomeExe.exe"

  Set WshShell1 = Nothing
  Set WshShell2 = Nothing


  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APPEXTRACTIONPATH won't be preserved until uninstall time unless you preserve it yourself, a WiX remember property should work for that. So that should allow your first custom action to start, although I don't understand why you need a cmd to do that. It seems to me that you basically just need to run [APPLICATIONPATH]UninstallManager.exe ...

If you're trying to invoke an MSI-based uninstall from your own uninstall then it won't work whatever you do, because recursive MSI operations aren't allowed (you typically get error 1618).

That second example: You should report the result returned from the shell run command. Again, it's not clear to me why you can't just run the executable instead of trying to wrap it with a cmd. Also, that second example reads HKCU, and you say it gets the correct value, and that means you are probably impersonating the current user (or you wouldn't see HKCU) so to get to the point your impersonate custom action is not elevated, and running that uninstall may require elevation.

Comment: I resolved this problem by using Custom Action Type 50. It was really simple and saved my day [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx)